# How do I prove that $|\Bbb N^\Bbb N|$ is equal to $|2^\Bbb N|$?

Tags: cardinals, natural-numbers

How do I prove that $|\Bbb N^\Bbb N|$ is equal to $|2^\Bbb N|$? I am very new to this subject an am looking for a solution with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: One inequality is easy, which one? show your effort.

Comment: Use [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), and notice that a sequence of natural numbers $(u_n)$ can be represented by a sequence of $0$s and $1$s, with $u_n$ consecutive $1$s separated by a $0$.

Comment: what do you mean with inequality?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To show $a=b$, show $a\le b$ and $b \le a$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ok how should I do that? I read through the Cantor-Bernstein theorem but dont know how to implement that in my proof.

Comment: Find two injections. The one from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is immediate since $2$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$. (if the preceding sentence looks cryptic, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)) The other one can be done with an "encoding" of sequences of natural numbers, as suggested above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$|2^\mathbb N|\leq|\mathbb N^\mathbb N|\leq\big|\big(2^\mathbb N\big)^\mathbb N\big|=|2^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}|=|2^\mathbb N|$$

The trickiest part of this statement to prove is $|\mathbb N^\mathbb N|\leq\big|\big(2^\mathbb N\big)^\mathbb N\big|$. We can construct an injection from the former to the latter as follows:$$\phi:\mathbb N^\mathbb N\to\big(2^\mathbb N\big)^\mathbb N$$$$f\mapsto g$$where $g(n)$ is the function $h_n:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ defined as follows $$h_n(m)=\begin{cases}0&m=f(n)\\1&m\neq f(n)\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you. I did it vice versa for |N^N|<=|2^N|. Do I now have to do this for |2^N| = |N^N| ?

Comment: $|2^\mathbb N|\leq|\mathbb N^\mathbb N|$ is clear since $\{0,1\}\subset\mathbb N$.